R studio unable to load properly
My R studio does not load properly. When I open it I get this error.
Any suggestions on how to handle this?
 sh: line 1:  5719 Abort trap: 6           '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4' -E -c 'import platform; print(platform.python_version())' 2>&1
 sh: line 1:  5721 Abort trap: 6           '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4' -E -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)' 2>&1


Has this just started to happen (ie were you able to run Python from RStudio before) ? The errors indicate you are using python 3.4 which is quite old. What do you get when you run these in a terminal: echo $PATH, which python, and which python3

echo $PATH
/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin

usernames-MacBook-Pro-3:~ username$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
usernames-MacBook-Pro-3:~ username$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
usernames-MacBook-Pro-3:~ username$

It was running fine before, I primarily use R studio and tried to fiddle with python recently and this has happened. it would be great if you can help me
