R workspace not loading correctly across two laptops
I have recently got a new mac and I am using dropbox to sync files. I am using the online version of dropbox and I could not get the same workspace I see in my old mac. I tried downloading and it still shows the same. But when I open my old mac I get a pop up that python quit unexpectedly but I can see the:
  sh: line 1:  6539 Abort trap: 6           '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4' -E -c 'import platform; print(platform.python_version())' 2>&1
  sh: line 1:  6541 Abort trap: 6           '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4' -E -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)' 2>&1
 [Workspace loaded from ~/Dropbox/..../.RData]

I do not get the same python error in new mac. But the workspace is not loaded correctly in new mac.
 [Workspace loaded from ~/Dropbox/..../.RData]

Any advise?
see more details in this link about the error

Is this just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78545895/r-studio-unable-to-load-properly with more details?

Those are two different issues but interrelated and perhaps it is triggered from some unknown cause. Help is much appreciated

Add more details. Why you say the workspace is not loaded correctly?
What are your python objects in workspace?
if you have reticulate references they're not saved between sessions

None of the R projects from workspace i.e. from old mac are not loading. The datasets are loaded but not the scripts. I do not have any python objects but when I open my R studio in old I am getting an error python quit unexpectedly and..I am updating the detailed error that I am getting in old mac..
